# Objeto de conexão com o banco: devo ter apenas um para todo o sistema ou uma instância por classe?

Tags: c#, .net, design-pattern, repository, padrão-dao

Qual é a melhor prática: ter apenas uma ponto (Singleton) que retorna as conexões ao banco de dados ou criar uma instancia da conexão para cada objeto?

Meu sistema acessa várias bancos e por isso criei uma classe `AcessoBanco` que, a partir de um arquivo `.INI` cria as conexões necessárias.

Meu projeto estava utilizando uma classe estática (Singleton) que devolvia as conexões de banco que eu preciso. Comecei a ter exceções esporádicas pois meu sistema é *multi-thread*. Resolvi criando *locks* para acesso exclusivo às propriedades que expõem as conexões, porém, fiquei em dúvida, isso é uma boa prática.

Imagino que se cada DAO criar sua própria instância das conexões, este problema de concorrência seria eliminado. Vou dar uns exemplos

#### Utilizando um Singleton

```
public class Repositorio1
{
    public Repositorio1(string caminhoArquivoINI)
    {
        AcessoBanco.Configurar(caminhoArquivoINI); // Singleton único que cria as conexões (gerava problemas de concorrencia resolvido com locks)

        // Depois de configurado basta usar AcessoBanco.ObterConexao() em qualquer ponto do código para obter uma conexão 
    }
}
```

#### Utilizando uma instancia por objeto

```
public class Repositorio2
{
    public AcessoBanco Conexoes { get; set; }

    public Repositorio2(string caminhoArquivoINI)
    {
        Conexoes = new AcessoBanco(caminhoArquivoINI); // Utilizando uma instancia por objeto. Isso tem que ser feito em toda classe que deseja acessar o banco.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O que é melhor sempre é complicado de afirmar sem um contexto específico.

As pessoas acham que criar conexões custa caro e e que haverá um processo complicado. Pelo menos é o que eu imagino, não estou na cabeça delas. Eu sei que muitos usam essa premissa, mas pode ser que só estão copiando o que viram errado por aí.

O fato é que o objeto de conexão é um *pool*, ele te entrega uma conexão conforme sua necessidade e sabe como gerenciar as conexões, e é um objeto bem pensado e desenvolvido por pessoas que entendem como fazer isso de forma correta. Tudo funciona perfeitamente, com performance de forma simplificada.

É até possível criar uma abstração simples para simplificar alguma coisa específica, mas criar um Singleton, ou uma substituta para a conexão, como ando vendo em quase todos os códigos que o pessoal posta aqui, é um absurdo, é um *antipattern*. É uma pessoa que pouco ou nada entende do assunto tentando criar uma coisa certamente pior para pouco ou nenhum ganho.

Portanto os dois casos apresentados parecem estar errados. Claro, não vi essa classe `AcessoBanco`, mas quase todo mundo faz errado.

Esses problemas relatados provavelmente ocorrem porque está implementando errado. E o correto é não implementar nada disso. Aí começa criar problemas novos para solucionar os problemas que sequer deveriam existir. Se fosse necessário uma abstração deste tipo para qualquer aplicação o .NET forneceria. Nunca implemente nada que não possa justificar com propriedade.

Eu acredito que o problema ocorre porque as pessoas tentam criar padrões de projeto sem nem entender que problema ele está resolvendo, isso inclui DAO ou repositório, em geral é bem complicado fazer certo, e quase sempre não dá o benefício que a pessoa acha que dará, ela só está fazendo o que "todo mundo" está fazendo, sem entender como fazer.

Pelo comentário parece não fazer sentido ter um Singleton, afinal tem conexões diferentes, é plural e não singular.

Comment: Sobre abrir conexão e fechar conexão pelo menor período de tempo, eu entendo isso e utilizo esta boa prática. Sobre pools, eu tbm entendo e sei como funciona.Meu problema é outro. No meu caso, o sistema conecta em um número variável de bancos de dados e eu preciso descobrir quais são estes bancos a partir de um arquivo .ini. De qualquer forma eu entendi o que você quis explicar.

Comment: Então não entendi o que deseja na pergunta.

Comment: Imagine o seguinte: Eu vou ter repositórios que acessam dados de mais de um banco, por exemplo: `SELECT * from Banco1.dbo.Tabela1 INNER JOIN Banco2.dbo.Tabela1`. Perceba que na minha classe repositório, eu preciso ter acesso à conexão do Banco1 e do Banco2. Atualmente elas estão neste Singleton que falei e eu acesso assim: MeuSingleton.ObterConexaoBanco1(); MeuSingleton.ObterConexaoBanco1(); entendeu? Foi só por isso que criei um Singleton. Assim todos os repositórios acessam o mesmo Singleton. Minha pergunta é se isso é boa prática ou tem jeito melhor de se fazer.

Comment: Eu outras palavras: é boa prática expor essas conexões que preciso no Singleton e deixar que os repositórios acessem as conexões que eles precisam ou devo passar as conexões para o repositório (por um construtor, por exemplo).